# Changing a Sum to Closed Form

Tags: probability

Okay so I have the probability of an event as being equal to

$$P_=\left( \frac 78\right)^{i-1}\times \frac 19\times \left(\frac {14}{15}\right)^{n-i}$$

And I'm wondering how if at all I can translate this equation into the form $\sum_{i=1}^{n}P$. Or in other words, I'm wondering if generally we can get all the $n$ terms on one side to get a cleaner easier to work with equation.

If you have any tips or ideas, they would be very appreciated!

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} x^i = \frac{x(1-x^n)}{1-x}
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

First you need to separate everything which doesn't contain $i$:

$$\left( \frac 78\right)^{i-1} \frac 19 \left(\frac {14}{15}\right)^{n-i}=\frac19 \cdot \frac87 \left( \frac{14}{15} \right)^n  \left( \frac 78 \times \frac{15}{14} \right)^i$$

$$\left( \frac 78 \times \frac{15}{14} \right)^i=\left( \frac{15}{16} \right)^i$$

Now since we have a [geometric sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) (and remembering Donald Splutterwit comment):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{15}{16} \right)^i=\frac{\frac{15}{16} \left(1- \left( \frac{15}{16} \right)^n \right)}{1-\frac{15}{16}}=15 \left(1- \left( \frac{15}{16} \right)^n\right)$$

Finally:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \left( \frac 78\right)^{i-1} \frac 19 \left(\frac {14}{15}\right)^{n-i}=\frac{40}{21}  \left( \frac{14}{15} \right)^n \left(1- \left( \frac{15}{16} \right)^n\right)=$$

> $$=\frac{40}{21} \left(\left( \frac{14}{15} \right)^n- \left( \frac{7}{8} \right)^n\right)$$

You can check for several values of $n$ to make sure this formula holds.

Comment: notice that $\frac{7}{8}=\frac{14}{16}$ and $\frac{14}{15}$ are very close.

If you want, try to tell how does the answer depend on $n$ and why?

---

I'm sure you can also write the general closed form for:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n x^i y^{n-i}$$